# RegEx to find the word between last Upper Case word and another word

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

My problem is to find a word between two words. Out of these two words one is an all UPPER CASE word which can be anything and the other word is "is". I tried out few regexes but none are helping me. Here is my example:

String :

```
In THE house BIG BLACK cat is very good.
```

Expected output :

```
cat
```

RegEx used  :

```
(?<=[A-Z]*\s)(.*?)(?=\sis)
```

The above RegEx gives me `BIG BLACK cat` as output whereas I just need `cat`.

Comment: Though I got answer to my question. I was just trying to figure out the regex for below scenario:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
String TestInput = "In THE house BIG BLACK cat is very good.";
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile(
                    "(?<=\\b\\p{Lu}+\\s)  # lookbehind assertion to ensure a uppercase word before\n"
                            + "\\p{L}+    # matching at least one letter\n" 
                            + "(?=\\sis)  # lookahead assertion to ensure a whitespace is ahead\n"
                            , Pattern.COMMENTS);    Matcher m = p.matcher(TestInput);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

it matches only "cat".

`\p{L}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for a letter in any language.

`\p{Lu}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for an uppercase letter in any language.

Comment: After reading the question a couple more times, I really think this is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works for even Unicode characters. Cheers!

Comment: @stema Though I got answer to my question. I was just trying to figure out the regex for below scenario:  match all words between the last upper case word in a string and some other word.  For e.g., in the string "In THE house BIUG BLACK cat is very good"  Match all words between BLACK [as this is the last upper case word] and very.  So my matched string will be "cat is"

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to simplify your regular expression a bit,

```
[A-Z]+\s(\w+)\sis
```

and use only the matched group (i.e., `\1`).  [See it in action here.](http://regex101.com/r/bT1hL4)

Since you came up with something more complex, I assume you understand all the parts of the above expression but for someone who might come along later, here are more details:

- `[A-Z]+` will match one or more upper-case characters
- `\s` will match a space
- `(\w+)` will match one or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and store the match in the first match group
- `\s` will match a space
- `is` will match "is"

My example is very specific and may break down for different input.  Your question didn't provided many details about what other inputs you expect, so I'm not confident my solution will work in all cases.

Comment: But unfortunately also wrong, the OP asked `[...] whereas I just need cat.` and that's not what this regex gives if you use it as is. But the regex in general is very good :)

Comment: @avalancha I'm a little confused.  The regular expression provides 'cat', and OP said he needed 'cat'.  How is it wrong?

Comment: I tried the regex [here](http://regexpal.com/) and it highlights `BIG BLACK CAT`. SO I thought you need grouping to get **only** cat. Hope I'm not mistaken...

Comment: @avalancha Take only the matched group :) Thats it :)

Comment: Ah so we were thinking the same thing! I think an answer should provide information about the grouping, though.

Comment: Upvoted for explaining the regex. It always helps when people explain rather than just leave people to parrot the solution. Sure, some will still just parrot, but at least the explanation gives them the option not to.

Comment: @ufis I somewhat agree, but that's why SO asks users to check google before asking a question. The OP in this case seems to have done that, he seems to know how regexes work

Comment: @avalancha And now this answer (with explanation) will also start to show up on Google. I use regex so infrequently that I have to Google it every time. For people like me it helps that the specific explanations are with the answer so I do not have to go elsewhere to find out how it works. But I get what you are saying.

Comment: @lostriebo Thanks for your detailed explanation but a solution from rbernabe and stema below gave me exactly what I needed. I have to use the look aheads in my applciation. But great thanks for making things so clear

Answer (score 2):

You want to look for a condition that depends on several parts of infirmation and then only retrieve a specific part of that information. That is not possible in a regex without grouping. In Java you should do it like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+\\s(\\w+)\\sis");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("In THE house BIG BLACK cat is very good.");

        if (matcher.find())
           System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

The `group(1)` is the one with brackets around it. In this case `w+`. And that's your word. The return type of `group()` is `String` so you can use it right away

Comment: Upvoted for showing the java implementation and explaining the `group(1)`. I learned something new here.

Comment: Of course it is possible without grouping *to look for a condition that depends on several parts of information and then only retrieve a specific part of that information*. The OP has not been far away.

Answer (score 2):

The following part has a extrange behavior

```
(?<=[A-Z]*\s)(.*?)
```

For some reason `[A-Z]*` is matching a empty string. And `(.*?)` is matching `BIG BLACK`. With a little tweaks, I think the following will work (but it still matches some false positives):

```
(?<=[A-Z]+\s)(\w+)(?=\sis)
```

A slightly better regex would be:

```
(?<=\b[A-Z]+\s)(\w+)(?=\sis)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 String  m = "In THE house BIG BLACK cat is very good.";
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+\\s\\w+\\sis");
       Matcher m1 = p.matcher(m);
       if(m1.find()){
        String group []= m1.group().split("\\s");// split by space
        System.out.println(group[1]);// print the 2 position 
       }
```